# Tableau embedded data source refresh using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, tableau-api

Is there a way to refresh Tableau **embedded datasource** using python. I am currently using Tableau server client library to refresh published datasources which is actually working fine. Can someone help me to figure out a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you can reach them is kinda annoying from my perpective.
You need to use `populate_connections()` function to load embedded datasources. It would be easier if you know the name of the workbook.

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

#sign in using personal access token
server = TSC.Server(server_address='server_name', use_server_version=True)
server.auth.sign_in_with_personal_access_token(auth_req=TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(token_name='tokenName', personal_access_token='tokenValue', site_id='site_name'))

#use RequestOptions() with a filter to pull an specific workbook
def get_workbook(name):
    req_opt = TSC.RequestOptions()
    req_opt.filter.add(TSC.Filter(req_opt.Field.Name, req_opt.Operator.Equals, name))
    return server.workbooks.get(req_opt)[0][0] #workbooks.get () function is intended to return a list items that you can iterate, but here we are assuming it will be find  only one result

workbook = get_workbook(name='workbook_name') #gets the workbook
server.workbooks.populate_connections(workbook) #this function will load all the embedded datasources in the workbook
for datasource in workbook.connections: #iterate in datasource list
    #Note: each element of this list is not an TSC.DatabaseItem, so, you will need to load a valid one using the "datasource_id" attribute from the element.
    #If you try server.datasources.refresh(datasource) it will fail
    ds = server.datasources.get_by_id(datasource.datasource_id) #loads a valid TSC.DatabaseItem
    server.datasources.refresh(ds) #finally, you will be able to refresh it
    ...
```

The best practice is do not embeddeding datasources but publish them independently.

Update: 
There is an easy way to achieve this. There are two types of extract tasks, Workbook and Data source. So, for embedded data sources, you need to perform a workbook refresh.

```
workbook = get_workbook(name='workbook_name')
server.workbooks.refresh(workbook.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "tableauserverclient" Python package. You can pip install it from PyPy. 
After installing it, you can consult the docs.

I will attach an example I used some time ago:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('user', 'pass', 'homepage')
server = TSC.Server('server')

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_datasources, pagination_item = server.datasources.get()
    print("\nThere are {} datasources on 
    site:".format(pagination_item.total_available))
    print([datasource.name for datasource in all_datasources])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am already using the 'tableauserverclient' package and mentioned code snippet to get the all the list of data sources present in the server which is working fine but embedded data sources are not getting displayed. I need help with that.